# Indefinite integral $ \int\frac{ \cos 2x}{\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

Can someone help me with this integral:

$$\int\frac{\cos 2x}{\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x}\,dx$$

I don't understand why $\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x$ is not equal to $1$.
Unfortunately, Wolfram doesn't show step by step solution. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: $\sin^2 +\cos^2 x=1$ but that says nothing about $\sin^3 +\cos^3 x$, $\sin^4 +\cos^4 x$, or higher powers. If you could factor $\sin^4 +\cos^4 x$ that would help.

Comment: the Pythagorean Theorem states that $c^2=a^2+b^2$. Dividing both sides by $c^2$ we get $1=(\frac{a}{c})^2+(\frac{b}{c})^2$, or alternatively $1=\sin^2 x +\cos^2 x$.

Answer (score 6):

The reason why is that $$\left(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)\right)^2=\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)+2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)=1^2=1$$ So, $$\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)=1-2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)=1-\frac 12 \sin^2(2x)$$ So $$I=\int \frac{\cos (2x)}{\sin^4 (x)+\cos^4 (x)}dx=\int \frac{\cos (2x)}{1-\frac 12 \sin^2(2x)}dx$$

Now, there is a beautiful thing here. I let you the pleasure of finding it and finishing the problem.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I've imagine that was that equality the problem.

Comment: You are welcome ! **Happy New Year !!!**

Comment: Claude, sorry for the Off topic, I just wanted to tell that I love your answer. I find them really kind and well explained! A happy new year to you too :D

Comment: nice..................+1

Answer (score 2):

Here are two substitutions that fit this integral well:

1) Since
$$
\frac{\cos 2x}{\cos^4x+\sin^4x}=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^4x}
$$
we let $u=\tan x$. This will transform the integral into
$$
\int \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^4}\,du.
$$
2) Next, in the spirit of @juantheron, let $v=u+1/u$. This will transform the integral into
$$
\int \frac{1}{2-v^2}\,dv=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\text{artanh}\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}+C.
$$
I leave it to you to do the substitutions back to the $x$ variable.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sin^4x+\cos^4x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-\dfrac{(\sin2x)^2}2$$

Let $\sin2x=u$